# How to align data with different lengths in table format

Tags: java, alignment

Notice how the '0' of the collisions column in the 3rd line is shifted, as well as other numbers, what is a fix to that? [[image: image1][1]]

This is my current output
System.out.println(""+capacity +"\t\t\t "+size()+"\t\t "+num+"\t\t"+ data + "\t\t\t" + collisions)

Answer (score 0):

I would start by precomputing the lengths of all of the header fields. Then use that and formatted io to build a table programmatically. Something like,

```
String[] headings = {
        "Capacity",
        "Size",
        "Num",
        "data",
        "Collisions"
};
int[] lengths = new int[headings.length];
for (int i = 0; i < headings.length; i++) {
    lengths[i] = headings[i].length() + 4;
}
int[][] values = {
        { 100, 1, 1, 241, 0 },
        { 100, 2, 1, 289, 0 },
        { 100, 3, 1, 4, 0 }
};
for (int i = 0; i < headings.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%-" + lengths[i] + "s", headings[i]);
}
System.out.println();
for (int i : lengths) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        System.out.print("=");
    }
}
System.out.println();
for (int[] arr : values) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%-" + lengths[i] + "s", arr[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Outputs

```
Capacity    Size    Num    data    Collisions    
=================================================
100         1       1      241     0             
100         2       1      289     0             
100         3       1      4       0
```

Comment: Is there not a way to do it using /t or something ... I'm using linked lists and its seems there must be an easier way to do it no?

Comment: You've tried that already. Probably should include more of your code in your question.